# How to ignore crash notifications / uninstall apps without booting on CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes, uninstallation

Today I upgraded CyanogenMod to the latest build (05/10/2015) on my Nexus 4 and installed the newest GApps package. But as soon as I boot my device now, my phone spams crash notifications for Gmail, Youtube and GApps processes. They pop up immediately again after I close them.

I read about solving this by clearing the cache / data of my Google apps. But I can't do anything, those messages block my phone. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

U can use your recovery to uninstall apps. Look here for info http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1610121

But I guess it's not the best solution to uninstall all Google apps. Try finding some other, suitable for your ROM, set of gapps. Try these https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934542272 for cm12

and these http://fitsnugly.euroskank.com/?rom=banks&device=gapps for cm 12.1